# Why won't my index variable increment when ASP.NET Timer Tick event is handled?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, timer

This is a bit of an interesting question. I have an ASP.NET Timer (`Timer1`) that is supposed to increment an integer variable that I am using to keep track of which item in a menu is selected. Have a look at the Tick event handler.

'Menu_RightSide.Items(TimerMenuIndex).Selected = True`

```
Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Select Case TimerMenuIndex
            Case 0
                bindDataToChart_locationChrono() 
                TimerMenuIndex += 1
            Case 1
                BindCurrentProgressDataToChart() 
                TimerMenuIndex += 1
            Case 2
                bindDBDataToChart()                   
                TimerMenuIndex += 1
            Case Else
                'Do Something else         
    End Select
End Sub
```

This seems like it should be relatively simple logic. All I want is for the `TimerMenuIndex` variable to increment by one when the Tick event handler function is called. However, for some reason, it will not increment.I should mention that `TimerMenuIndex` is a global variable. I know that the Timer control is AJAX-based, so it shouldn't be calling the `Page_Load` function when the Timer refreshes the page. I can't think of any reason why this doesn't work. I could be missing something very obvious. Any thoughts?

UPDATE: Here is the `Page_Load` code that pertains to this functionality:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
     Menu_RightSide.Items(TimerMenuIndex).Selected = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you might find it does fire page_load because it is a partial postback. Show the code for the page load as well

Comment: I have updated the question with the requested information.

Comment: @ic3man7019 you have a script manager ?

Comment: @meda Yes there is a ScriptManager present.

Comment: please go through this guide and see if you missed something https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: @meda I have gone through those steps 15 times lol. The Timer is actually doing everything else it's supposed to. It's updating the other panels on the page just fine; it just won't change the value of the TimerMenuIndex variable.

Comment: did you debug this, add breakpoints and step trough that code, is it entering the switch case

Comment: Yes. I am sure that it is getting into the switch case block. The value of the TimerMenuIndex variable simply won't increment.

Comment: @ic3man7019 see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is the variable gets reset to `0` after the tick event.

You need to declare Shared, this will make the variable retain its value, and

```
Shared TimerMenuIndex As Integer = 0
```

[I created a sample application for you to try](https://mega.nz/#!fMhVVLzZ)

Comment: This is correct. I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you!